# Android - remove three dots in SearchView

Tags: android, android-layout, material-design

How can I remove the three dots to the right of my `SearchView` ?

[image]

Comment: Only when the SearchView is open or always?

Comment: @GSala  Only when the SearchView is open

Answer (score 0):

set false in onPrepareOptionsMenu

```
@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu (Menu menu) {
return false;
 }
```

Comment: it removed all items on Toolbar

Comment: what do you mean ?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this helps you

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_activity, menu);

    MenuItem searchMI = (MenuItem) menu.findItem(R.id.menu_search);
    searchMI.setOnActionExpandListener(new OnActionExpandListener(){
        @Override
        public boolean onMenuItemActionCollapse(MenuItem menuItem) {
            // Hide menu icon
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onMenuItemActionExpand(MenuItem menuItem) {
            // Show menu icon
            return true;
        }
    });
    return true;
}
```

You can show or hide icons like this:

```
menu.findItem(R.id.yourActionId).setVisible(true);
menu.findItem(R.id.yourActionId).setVisible(false);
```

Comment: It throw me an error: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: This is not supported, use MenuItemCompat.setOnActionExpandListener()

Comment: @athene Have you tried what it says? Using `MenuItemCompat.setOnActionExpandListener`instead of `setOnActionExpandListener`? The rest of the code should be the same

Answer (score 0):

You need to hide all others menu items one by one...

```
@Override
public boolean onMenuItemActionExpand (MenuItem item){
   menu.getItem(MENU_MAIN_REFRESH).setVisible(false);
   menu.getItem(MENU_MAIN_SETTINGS).setVisible(false);
   menu.getItem(MENU_MAIN_EXIT).setVisible(false);
   return true;
}
```